# I am trying to create a class for a store product, when i try to print the object i made using my class it gives me the message "exercise_93.Product"

Tags: c#, class

```
using System;

  namespace exercise_93
  {
   class Program
   {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {  
        // creating objects using my class
        Product apple = new Product("apple",1.1,13);
        Product banana = new Product("banana",1.1,13);
        //trying to print out my object (but it prints out exercise_93.Product instead)
        Console.WriteLine(banana.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

> below is my code for the class i created.

```
     namespace exercise_93
       {
         public class Product
        {
           public string ProductName;
           public double ProductPrize;
           public int ProductAmount;
           // Constructor for my class.
           Product(string Name,double Prize,int Amount)
           {
            this.ProductName = Name;
            this.ProductPrize = Prize;
            this.ProductAmount = Amount;
           }   
        }    
      }
```

> When i try to print the object it just prints out the namespace and class name  instead.
> // do i have to create a specific method to print out the information of the class?

Comment: You are asking an instance of Product to show itself as a string. But your class has no way to do that, so the base class of everything in NET (The Object class) comes to the rescue providing its implementation of the conversion of a class to a string. Its default is to print the class' name. If you want a different implementation then your Product class should override the ToString() method exposed by the Object class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to override the .ToString() method so that the program knows how a string value of this object is supposed to look.

```
public ExampleClass()
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"PropertyA: {propertyA}. PropertyB:{propertyB}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the properties of the object to get the actual value.

If you want to write each property to the console, use

```
Console.WriteLine(banana.ProductName);
Console.WriteLine(banana.ProductPrize.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(banana.ProductAmount.ToString());
```

Then do the same for apple.

You could do a loop with [Reflection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwizo9TXv_fzAhXRK80KHbMPB-AQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fcsharp%2Fprogramming-guide%2Fconcepts%2Freflection&usg=AOvVaw1WWfVjV14tXJdxY9NtoeeB), but that's probably more advanced than what you need here.